# ERROR: AttributeError :: type object 'Loader' has no attribute 'BUILTIN_DATA_PATH'

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, attributeerror, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

Since today, I am unable to deploy to my AWS EC2 instance. 
When hitting "eb deploy" I get the following error:

```
ERROR: AttributeError :: type object 'Loader' has no attribute 'BUILTIN_DATA_PATH'
```

Can anyone help me how to set or reconfigure the 'BUILTIN_DATA_PATH' object?

Thanks!

Comment: I am using aws-cli/1.10.22 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/15.4.0 botocore/1.4.13

Answer (score 0):

I would love to help but I would need some more context. It looks like it might be the way you have setup python in your environment. Do all `eb` commands fail with this same error? Can you run the command with the `--debug` flag and post the output?

I would try setting up python and the EB CLI in a brand new environment. I recommend using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper to create and manage your python virtual environments to work in.

Here is a [quick start guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for setting up a virtual environment.